# Blender 2.82 issue - flat texture and i can't manipulate the object

Tags: object-mode

that's happen when I try to move/scale/roatate an object on Object Mode:

[image]

the orange are selected but the gray box isn't.

Comment: Hi. Please make the title of the question specific to what you are asking and not just the general topic. Thanks.

Comment: What is the problem, exactly? And how to you proceed to move on object? By cliking on move button, or with keyboard shortcut G?